# Probability of tails immediately following heads

Tags: probability

**Question**

Find the minimum number of times you would have to toss a fair coin so as to be at least $99.8\%$ confident that tails immediately follows heads at least once.

**My working**

Consider the complements (essentially the cases where there is no "HT"):

*Case 1*

There is $0$ consecutive tails followed by $n$ consecutive heads

*Case 2*

There is $1$ consecutive tails followed by $n$ consecutive heads

*Case 3*

There is $2$ consecutive tails followed by $n$ consecutive heads

$\vdots$

where $n$ is a non-negative number.

However, I do not know how to proceed with the calculations as both the number of tails and heads are unknown.

Any intuitive explanation will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The only scenarios for which a tails does *not* follow a heads would be if all flips were tails, or if all flips were tails up until a certain point and were all heads after, or if all flips were heads.  Make sure that you are comfortable with why that must be so.  Suppose that $n$ coins were flipped in all (*here, $n$ being total number of coins... not just total number of heads*).  What is the probability that all coins were tails?  What is the probability that all coins were tails except the last which was heads?  And so on...  What then is the probability no tail followed a head?

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't the probability of all these cases are $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} $?

Comment: Yes, and there are $n+1$ such cases.  There is no overlap between cases, so we can add them together to get $\dfrac{n+1}{2^n}$ as the probability of no tails following a head if $n$ coins are flipped.  Now it is a matter of arithmetic and algebra to find what the smallest $n$ is such that $\dfrac{n+1}{2^n}\leq 0.002$